# Using a marker interface to restrict generic parameter

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have a class Foo which can handle a certain type of variables. I want to restrict this type to a few classes I have. These classes have been implemented but don't have any inheritance relationship. Does it make sense to write an empty interface Type and then adding 'implements Type' to all classes that are an accepted type for the generic parameter T.

This would mean you would get something like this:

```
public class SuperFoo() {
    //Some code
}

public class Foo<T extends Fooable> extends SuperFoo {
    private T acceptedObject;
    private String name;

    public Foo(String name, T acceptedObject) {
        this.name = name;
        this.acceptedObject = acceptedObject;
        //Some code
    }
}

public interface Fooable {}

public class FooableClass1 implements Fooable {  //Objects of this class will be accepted as T
    public FooableClass1() {}
    //Some code
}

public class FooableClass2 implements Fooable { //Object of this class will also be accepted as T
    public FooableClass1() {}
    //Some code
}

public class AnotherClass { //Objects of this class will not be accepted as T
    //Some code
}
```

EDIT: Thanks for the answers already, I changed the above code. I have an additional question for this part of code. If I wanted to implement a method in another class that creates a new instance of the class SuperFoo (the superclass of Foo), how would I do this?

This method would be something like :

```
public SuperFoo createNewFoo(String name, Type type) {
    //Calls the constructor of Foo and returns the object but how?
    //The type parameter decides whether the constructor of FooableClass1 
    //or the constructor of FooableClass2 is called.
}
```

How would I implement the class Type? An object of this class would just contain the information on which type of Fooable an object should be.

Comment: That's just fine. Marker interfaces don't hurt.

Comment: But adding `()` after  `implements Type` does!

Comment: My bad :) If I was to accept Boolean as a possible type for T, what would be the best way to do that? Making a wrapper class for boolean which extends Type?

Comment: @Wonano That seems like a *valid* thing but it's tough to say if it's the *best* without seeing more specifics of your code. If you're interested in that maybe try posting some of your real code to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @CaptainMan except CR will close this question in a matter of seconds as *hypothetical code* filled with `// some code` comments is plain off-topic.

Comment: @Mat I meant the real code, edited above to clarify.

Comment: What is the *reason* for the restriction?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making an `interface` called `Fooable`. [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) is a good example of this in the java api, which is a strong argument that this is kosher.